# MvcSitemapProvider.Mvc5 is not working after installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2, mvcsitemapprovider

1) After installing MvcSiteMapProvider.mvc5 via nuget, I get an exception when running my mvc site via localhost and the error stating: `Could not find file 'C:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects....\Mvc.sitemap'.`

I used the instructions below: https://web.archive.org/web/20160424031041/http://www.shiningtreasures.com:80/post/2013/08/07/MvcSiteMapProvider-40-a-test-drive

2) I also add this `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()` to the layout file as below but no breadcrumb displayed on screen.

```
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html;

@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

3) Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates folder is empty. There are no files such as SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml.

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Note: The installation went fine and I can see the MvcSiteMapProvider.dll file in the bin folder.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that is is old now but I had this same issue and thought I would share what I did to fix it for anybody else. It still seems to be an issue even with the latest version (though that was released a long time ago now).

Basically, the build via NuGet seems to be broken in that it does'nt add some files that it needs too. Specfically the "DisplayTemplates" folder and its contents.

I had to add the "DisplayTemplates" folder into Views/Shared myself.

You can get the contents of the folder out of the repository https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider.Sample.Mvc5/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates.

You may also need to add the config into Web.Config (I already added this myself anyway)which you can get from https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider

After I added the display templates folder and its content in, it worked for me. My issue was specifically it not working when it got deployed to a web server. It worked fine on localhost out of the box for me but didnt display when deployed.

Hope this helps someone